How to get Zsh to tab-complete to the next file when already completed?
I have a series of files I want to open. I open the first like this:
rifle ~/path/to/myfile-part1-title.mp4

I watch the video, close the terminal and the next day I want to watch part2. So I hit CTRL-R and type myfile so that the last part I watched appears in the Zsh history.
I then have to press backspace to remove 1-title.mp4, then press 2 to autocomplete to the next part.
I'm looking for a faster way to do this. Ideally I'd like to press a tab again and Zsh would complete to the next part, without me having to manually remove the extra text and start typing the name of the next file. In this case, it should complete to this:
rifle ~/path/to/myfile-part2-other-title.mp4

Is there any way to accomplish this in Zsh?
Note: Not all files have this format. I would want to use this method for a different series of files eventually which may be titled like myotherfile_03x04.x265.blabla.mp4 etc.

You mean to the next file in the sorted list of all files in ~/path/to or in the list of those that start with myfile (then how would the prefix be determined) or the list of .mp4 files?

Yes to the next file in the directory. So basically what would come after that if you type ls ~/path/to/
